# divide array in to sub arrays java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an array like 1,2,3,4
 need to divide into

```
int [] array = { 1, 2, 3 , 4}

for( int i= 0; i < array .length-0; i ++) {
  Integer[] intArrays = array .stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
 //processing with stream
}


123, 234,34,4
sum of the each grouping 
1+2+3 =6
2+3+4 = 9
3+4 = 7
4=4
```

I can do it from java traditional way but need to implement  using java 8 stream concept

can you help me to do that

Comment: The groupings don't make sense. Is the first one supposed to be 1+2+3+4? And why is the last grouping 4+4? Maybe just 4?

Comment: sorry it should be eqaul sign

Comment: if you can do it 123, 234 that also enough for me

Comment: @Kasunshan why is the first `123`, shouldn't it be `1234`?

Comment: @Aominè no it should be 123 then start with next element 2 like that

Comment: Then the algorithm is unclear. What if the list was `{2,4,6,8,10,12}`? Please edit your question for clarity otherwise it'll have to be closed for being unclear.

Comment: @AdamKipnis then I think it would be `2+4+6=12
4+6+8=18
6+8+10=24
8+10+12=30
10+12=22
12=12` ?  Kasun is this correct? otherwise you'll need to further clarify your question

Comment: @Aominè Do you know how if list is integer array how could I achive this List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

Comment: @Kasunshan which code snippet of my answer do you want to modify to work with a `List<Integer>`? first, second or third?

Comment: @Aominè third one thanks

Comment: @Kasunshan `IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                .map(i -> list.stream().skip(i).limit(Math.min(3, list.size()-i)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum())
                .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);` .

Comment: What’s the relevance of this nonworking conversion from `int[]` to `Integer[]` in your question? It doesn’t match anything of your problem description. And why “minus zero”?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may get a little bit complex if you actually want the result as:

```
1+2+3 =6
2+3+4 = 9
3+4 = 7
4=4
```

In which case you can either do it as follows:

```
String result = IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(array).skip(i).limit(Math.min(3, array.length-i)).toArray())
                .map(a -> String.join("+",
                        Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new)) + "=" +
                        Arrays.stream(a).sum())
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(result);
```

or as follows:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length)
         .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(array).skip(i).limit(Math.min(3, array.length-i)).toArray())
         .map(a -> String.join("+",
                    Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(String::valueOf).toArray(String[]::new)) + "=" +
                    Arrays.stream(a).sum())
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

However, if the expected result can be as simple as printing the result of each group summation then it can be done as follows:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length)
         .map(i -> Arrays.stream(array).skip(i).limit(Math.min(3, array.length-i)).sum())
         .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

**Explanation:**

The first code snippet uses [Instream.range](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to generate the indices of the source array, then within the [mapToObj](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) operation it skips the necessary amount of elements and retains only the necessary amount of elements. Then with `map` we join the elements in each group as well as calculating the summation of them and then as for getting it in the format we want, finally, we join the strings with the [joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) collector.

The second code snippet does the same but instead of joining the strings with the [joining](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) collector, simply prints them to the console.

The last approach does a similar thing in regards to the mapping but is only concerned with the result of each group summation.

Comment: You can use `Arrays.stream(array, i, Math.min(i+3, array.length))` instead of chaining `skip` and `limit`, but when the only chained operation is `toArray`, you can use `Arrays.copyOfRange(array, i, Math.min(i+3, array.length))` in the first place. And I wouldn’t use `toArray`, just to call `String.join` when there is `collect(Collectors.joining(…))`; this collector can also get combined with the second stream operation: `.map(a -> Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(String::valueOf) .collect(Collectors.joining("+", "", "="+Arrays.stream(a).sum())))`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming the request is to limit each grouping to 3 elements. If so,

```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);

for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
  l.set(i, l.stream().skip(i).limit(3).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum());
}
```

Comment: or you could do `IntStream.range(0, l.size()).forEachOrdered(i -> l.set(i, l.stream().skip(i).limit(3).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()));` if you wanted to avoid the external iteration.